# Back Up & Restore Text Messages to Android & iPhone

Tags: android, iphone-app

I switch back and forth between Android & iPhone(I switch fairly regularly).
There are more then a couple apps that allow you to restore text messages on Andorid.

I would like some mechanism that ideally lets me restore to either iPhone or Android.